# count number of groups of certain element

Tags: scala, collections

I have a list, I need to count the number of groups of certain elements(1 or 0).

```
(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

val count1Grp = daysSequence.foldLeft(List[Int]()){(acc, elem) =>
  if(acc.isEmpty) elem :: acc else if(acc.head == elem) acc else elem :: acc
}
.count(_ == 1)

val count0Grp = daysSequence.foldLeft(List[Int]()){(acc, elem) =>
  if(acc.isEmpty) elem :: acc else if(acc.head == elem) acc else elem :: acc
}
.count(_ == 0)
```

I fold similar neighbour elements and then do a count of what is left. And get

```
count1Grp = 1
count0Grp = 1
```

Another example. Both rows same result.

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
count1Grp = 1
count0Grp = 2
```

But how should I do it if I needed 2 or more similar elements together to quantify as a group? In the first case 0 wouldn't fit the criteria and should result in

```
count1Grp = 1
count0Grp = 0
```

Comment: This seems like a good use case for tail-recursion or a `foldLeft` using a `State` class that can properly encode what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not get a `Map` with a count of every group in the collection? Then only one traversal is needed.

```
def groupCount[A](xs      : Seq[A]
                 ,grpSize : Int = 1
                 ,acc     : Map[A,Int] = Map[A,Int]()
                 ): Map[A,Int] = xs match {
  case Seq() => acc
  case hd +: _ =>
    val (grp,rest) = xs.span(_ == hd)
    if (grp.size < grpSize)
      groupCount(rest, grpSize, acc)
    else
      groupCount(rest, grpSize, acc + (hd -> (acc.getOrElse(hd,0)+1)))
}
```

Here's a [Scastie session](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WQtyJCOjTFOJkinJsZ7YGQ) with a few usage examples.